# Implementing: private structs in Class

Tags: c++, struct, iterator, private

I have a List class which uses two objects: Element & Iterator

I considered making Element & Iterator classes but decided on structs.

### V1. This works...

```
template <class T>
struct Element

template <class T>
struct Iterator



template <typename T>
class List {

public: 

typedef Iterator<T> iterator;


private:

};
```

Which allows a List iterator as you might expect:

```
List<int> list;
List<int>::iterator iter = list.begin();
```

### V2. Another way is to declare the structs inside the class

```
template <typename T>
class List {

public:

    template <class T>
    struct Element

    template <class T>
    struct Iterator


private:


};
```

However having to include the second <> when creating iterator is a little less elegant & structs are public:

```
List<int> list;
List<int>::Iterator<int> iter = list.begin();
```

### V3. Involves making the structs private, which is preferable:

```
template <class T>
class Iterator;


template <typename T>
class List {

public:


typedef Iterator<T> iterator;

private:

template <class T>
struct Element

template <class T>
struct Iterator

};
```

.

```
List<int> list;
List<int>::iterator iter list.begin();

Error 1 error C2079: 'begin' uses undefined class 'Iterator<T>'  main.cpp   216
```

### Question:

How do I make structs private, allow public access to Iterator & keep the **List::iterator** syntax ?

eg List::iterator iter list.begin();

note: 
Iterator depends on Element

code:

```
#ifndef GUARD_List_h
#define GUARD_List_h

template <class T>
struct Element {

    Element() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(), t_flag(" ") {}

    Element<T>* prev;
    Element<T>* next;

    T data;
    int elem_ID;
    std::string t_flag;
};

template <class T>
struct Iterator {

    Iterator(Element<T>* e = nullptr) : elem(e) {}

    T& operator*(void) const {

        if (elem->t_flag == "sentinel"){ std::cerr << "No Element to De-Reference - End of List Reached"; }

        return elem->data;
    }

    T& operator++(void) {           // ++prefix

        elem = elem->next;
        return elem->data;
    }
    T operator++(const int) {               // postfix++

        elem = elem->next;
        return elem->prev->data;
    }
    T& operator--(const int) {          // --prefix

        elem = elem->prev;
        return elem->data;
    }
    T operator--(void) {            // postfix--

        elem = elem->prev;
        return elem->next->data;
    }

    Iterator<T>& operator+(const int val) {

        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++){

            elem = elem->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Iterator<T>& operator-(const int val) {

        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++){

            elem = elem->prev;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID != rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }
    bool operator==(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID == rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }
    bool operator>(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID > rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }
    bool operator<(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID < rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }
    bool operator>=(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID >= rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }
    bool operator<=(const Iterator<T>& rhs) const {

        return elem->elem_ID <= rhs.elem->elem_ID;
    }


    Element<T>* elem;

};




template <typename T>
class List {

public:
    List() : sentinel(new Element<T>), Element_count(0)  {

        sentinel->t_flag = "sentinel";

        // double link: sentinel to itself
        sentinel->next = sentinel;
        sentinel->prev = sentinel;

    }
    virtual ~List()  {

        Element<T>* index = sentinel->next;
        Element<T>* index_next = sentinel->next->next;

        while (index->t_flag != "sentinel"){

            delete index;
            index = index_next;
            index_next = index_next->next;
        }
        delete sentinel;        
    }


    typedef Iterator<T> iterator;   


    Iterator<T> begin(void) const {

        Iterator<T> it(sentinel->next);
        return it;
    }
    Iterator<T> end(void) const {

        Iterator<T> it(sentinel);
        return it;
    }

    void push_back(const T val)  {

        Element<T>* elem = new Element<T>;      // create Element<T> object         
        elem->data = val;                       // set Element<T> data

        sentinel->prev->next = elem;            // link: end of List to Element object
        elem->prev = sentinel->prev;            // link: Element object to end of List   

        elem->next = sentinel;                  // link: new end of List to sentinel    
        sentinel->prev = elem;                  // link: sentinel to new end of List                

        elem->elem_ID = Element_count++;        // update: Element_count on grow        
    }
    T at(const size_t pos)  const {

        return get_Element(pos)->data;
    }
    void del(const size_t pos) const  {

        Element<T>* elem = get_Element(pos);    // get: Element for deletion        

        elem->prev->next = elem->next;          // rejoin: double link
        elem->next->prev = elem->prev;          // rejoin: double link

        delete elem;

        Element_count--;                        // update: Element_count on shrink

    }
    void clear(void) {

        Element<T>* index = sentinel->next;
        Element<T>* index_next = sentinel->next->next;

        while (index->t_flag != "sentinel"){

            delete index;
            index = index_next;
            index_next = index_next->next;
        }

        // double link: sentinel to itself
        sentinel->next = sentinel;
        sentinel->prev = sentinel;

        Element_count = 0;

    }

    size_t size(void) const {
        return Element_count;
    }
    bool empty(void) const {

        if (Element_count == 0){ return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }


private:



    Element<T>* sentinel;                         // List sentinel
    size_t Element_count;                         // List size

    Element<T>* get_Element(const size_t pos) const     {

        if (empty())                        {
            std::cerr << "No Element - Empty List";
            throw;          
        }
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= Element_count){
            std::cerr << "No Element - Out of Range";
            throw;          
        }


        Iterator<T> it;

        if ((Element_count / 2) > pos) {                        // Determine efficent direction ? 

            it = begin()+1;
            while ( it.elem->elem_ID != pos ){  it++;   }
        }
        else {

            it = end()-1;                           
            while ( it.elem->elem_ID != pos ){  it--;   }
        }

        return it.elem;
    }




};
#endif
```

Comment: You know the difference between a class in C++ and a struct, right? It's almost none. That said, I'd postpone the template parts until later, they are not necessary to answer your question but they complicate the issue.

Comment: What I mean is making them actual classes with their own header files...then including them.  But lets not get side tracked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as "elegance" is concerned, redundant `typename` declarations seem to be the biggest issue:

If you have a nested class or struct, you don't need to templetize it; it is already bound to the templetized `typename T` declaration.

So:

```
template <typename T>
class List {
public:
    struct Element;
    struct Iterator;
private:
};
```

Allows you to do:

```
List<int> x;
List<int>::iterator iter ( x.begin() );
```

Since `Iterator` is being returned in a public method, it cannot be marked `private`. `Element`, on the other hand, is purely an implementation detail and can be marked private. You need to make sure that it is declared before any method that uses it *or* is simply forward declared.

```
template<typename T>
class List {
private:
    struct Element; // or struct Element { <impl> };
public:
    struct Iterator { < impl > };
private:
};
```

Comment: Adding the structs as described gives a syntax error in Element:
Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : '<' ..no error if templetized!

Comment: do you still have lines like `Iterator(Element<T>* e = nullptr) : elem(e) {}` ? These should be replaced with `Iterator(Element *e = nullptr) : elem(e){}` etc.

Comment: Similarly `Iterator<T>& operator+(const int val)` becomes `Iterator& operator+(...)`

Comment: Many thanks guys, I kept Iterator public made Element private & forward declared Element like so: "class Element;" @EyasSh if you add this to your answer code I'll accept it!

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly.